# Is it possible to add a class to a child of a JSF Composite Component?

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

As the title says, I want to add a class to a child element of a composite component based on specified attributes.

This is my composite component **ButtonBar.xhtml**:

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="spacing" default="2"/>
    <composite:attribute name="disablePrimary" default="false"/>
</composite:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<composite:implementation>
    <div class="button-bar">
        <div class="col-sm-#{cc.attrs.spacing}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-#{12 - cc.attrs.spacing}">
            <h:panelGroup>
                <composite:insertChildren/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </div>
    </div>      
</composite:implementation>
```

Usage would look something like this **index.xhtml**:

```
<myCc:ButtonBar>
    <b:commandButton value="Save"   action="#{ctrl.save()}" />
    <b:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{ctrl.delete()}" />
    <b:commandButton value="Cancel" action="#{ctrl.cancel()}" />
</myCc:ButtonBar>
```

My css already has a class for primary buttons which highlights them a bit more. When not otherwise specified (via the `disablePrimary` attr), I want to add the class to the first child.

So is it possible to access/edit attributes of children which will be inserted into a composite component?

Otherwise I think I would do it by adding another class to the button-bar and style the first button via css with `.button-bar.firstIsPrimary button:first-child`. (Other ideas are welcome) Even though this would be not as good because I would have to manually copy all css rules for all the states a button can have (`active hover visited` etc.)